# how to get video aspects like width/height in flutter_vlc_player [flutter]?

Tags: flutter, dart, vlc

Hi how to get actually size of video I am streaming from the internet into my VLC_PLAYER in flutter? https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_vlc_player

i don't really know how it actually works and documentation for flutter vlc player is bad, I want to transmit http stream in mjpg format

code below allows me to transmit video but its aspect ratio is 4/3 (width/height)
my widget where I put that player is 16/9 so there are black stripes on sides,

**i want get actual size of stream to be able to modify parent's widget height/width**

is it possible?
i don't get the idea of listeners here and even if I initialize controller in init state I still get sh1t error like this

"LateInitializationError: Field '_viewId@2133035241' has not been initialized."

```
class HTTPstreamer extends StatefulWidget {
  const HTTPstreamer({super.key, required this.urlAdress});

  final String urlAdress;

  @override
  State<HTTPstreamer> createState() => _HTTPstreamerState();
}
class _HTTPstreamerState extends State<HTTPstreamer> {
  late VlcPlayerController _controller;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = VlcPlayerController.network(
      autoPlay: true,
      autoInitialize: true,
      widget.urlAdress,
      hwAcc: HwAcc.full,
      options: VlcPlayerOptions(
        advanced: VlcAdvancedOptions([
          VlcAdvancedOptions.networkCaching(2000),
        ]),
        http: VlcHttpOptions([
          VlcHttpOptions.httpReconnect(true),
        ]),
        rtp: VlcRtpOptions([
          VlcRtpOptions.rtpOverRtsp(true),
        ]),
      ),
    );
    _controller.addOnInitListener(() async {
      await _controller.startRendererScanning();
    });
    _controller.addOnRendererEventListener((type, id, name) {
      debugPrint('OnRendererEventListener $type $id $name');
    });

    _controller.initialize();

    _controller.addOnInitListener(() async {
      var x = await _controller.getVideoAspectRatio();
      print("video aspect ratio ${x}");
    });

    _controller.addOnInitListener(() async {
      var x = await _controller.getVideoScale();
      print("video scale ${x}");
    });

    safePrint("data source ${_controller.dataSourceType}");
  }

  @override
  void dispose() async {
    super.dispose();
    await _controller.stopRendererScanning();
    await _controller.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Center(
      child: SizedBox(
        width: screenSize.width,
        height: screenSize.width * 9 / 16,
        child: VlcPlayer(
            controller: _controller,
            aspectRatio: 16.0 / 9.0,
            placeholder: const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```